# How to change the Masonry width?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, masonry

I'm currently working on a WordPress theme and I've run into a problem that I can't seem to solve. I've created a footer area for widgets and want to run Masonry on it. When there is no Masonry running, then the widgets align in 3 columns on a 1920x1080 screen, which is what I am aiming for, but when the Masonry is activated, then all the widgets crash into one column. I've tried a lot of searches, but can't seem to find someone running into the same problem.

Here's a website I had lying around that i could upload the theme to, so you can see the problem: https://youtube.akusasdesign.com/

And I've added the whole theme to Github, so that you can look through my code. Hopefully, someone will be able to help me, cause I've run completely out of ideas as to what is causing the problem.

Github: https://github.com/AkusasDesign/Akusas-Studio